# Trouble calling javascript function from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to do the following:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<a id="random">before</a>   
<script>
function test(a)
  {
      document.getElementById('random').innerHTML="after with variable passed in";
  }
function test2()
  {
      document.getElementById('random').innerHTML="after without variable passed in";
  }
</script>
<?php $sample = "hi"; ?>

<button onClick="test(<?php echo $sample;?>)">withVariable</button>

<button onClick="test2()">withoutVariable</button>
</html>
```

If I click the "withoutVariable" button, the function test2() gets called perfectly because no variables are passed in to it. However, if I click the "withVariable" button the function test(a) is never being called for some reason. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Since `$sample` is a string literal you need to enclose it with `''`

```
<button onClick="test('<?php echo $sample;?>')">withVariable</button>
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I had asked earlier.. Such a small mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a string variable, then you need to add quotes around the value, like so:

```
<button onClick="test('<?php echo $sample;?>')">withVariable</button>
```